# Why doesnt Main recognize properties and methods declared in a inherited class?

Tags: c#

```
abstract class Geometry 
{
    public string Color {get; set;}
}


class Ring : Geometry 
{
    public double Radius {get; set;}
}

class Triangle : Geometry 
{

}

class Square : Geometry 
{

}
```

I want to add property radius only to class ring, but I have to declare radius also in geometry class if I want instances of Ring to have access to Radius property in Main, and then Main instances of  triangle and square also have access to radius  - which I dont want.

The same thing is with methods

I declare classes in Main like this:

```
Geometry ring1 = new Ring();
Geometry triangle1 = new Triangle();
Geometry square1 = new Square();
```

I know that it works with
Ring ring1 = new Ring();
but what if I want to declare it like this: Geometry ring1 = new Ring();
to put everything in an array of geometry objects?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read more about [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance) and [polymorphism](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-polymorphism#:%7E:text=In%20c%23%2C%20Polymorphism%20means%20providing,and%20another%20one%20is%20morphs.).

You can access derived properties through the base class via conversion, e.g.:

```
Geometry ring= new Ring();
var radius = (ring as Ring).Radius;
```

Comment: But I want to use something like ring.Radius, and I dont want to declare independent variable in Main. That is Impossible if it isnt Ring ring = new Ring(); ?

Comment: You can use (ring as Ring) without creating additional variables, I only created the radius variable to demonstrate how you can acess it.

Answer (score 0):

If you place everything in an array of type `Geometry` you don't want access to the radius. You want to handle all objects as a `Geometry` and since that class doesn't implement the radius is not visible without casting.

This becomes interesting when you have methods or properties that span all classes e.g. a method for calculating the area of a shape. They each can have their own implementation with the circle relying on the radius while a quare uses the length of a side.

After all you create an array of the shapes because they have something in common that you want to make use of.